# ScaleData() from Seurat causes crash on RStudio Cloud

Tags: r, seurat, rstudio

Using the sample data in the 2,700 PBMC clustering tutorial, the session crashes at the `ScaleData()` step. The progress bar remains at 0% and hangs, followed by an R crash. I've tried reducing the size for number of genes to scale at in a single computation with the argument `block.size` with no change. The Seurat S4 object is only ~70mb so I can't imagine I'm exceeding the RStudio Cloud 1gb RAM limitations.

If you'd like to check out the cloud instance I can add you to the workspace temporarily. There is a limit on members allowed in a workspace.

I've been trying to run this tutorial on another remote cluster in RStudio inside of a container (Singularity here vs. Docker in RStudio Cloud) and am hitting the same snag.

I get receive no errors from RStudio Cloud, but in the other evirnment I get this error:

`ERROR session hadabend; LOGGED FROM: rstudio::core::Error {anonymous}::rInit(const rstudio::r::session::RInitInfo&) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:563`.

On [this issue thread](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/5504) someone mentions it they receive this error message when hitting their RAM limits.

The source for `ScaleData()` can be found in the [Github repo](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/blob/65b77a9480281ef9ab1aa8816f7c781752092c18/R/preprocessing.R).

Comment: Are you following the tutorial exactly? I don't see `ScaleData` [in the tutorial](https://satijalab.org/seurat/pbmc3k_tutorial_1_4.html).

Comment: `RegressOut()` is a deprecated function, regression now happens in the data scaling step. `vars.to.regress` is now passed as an argument to `ScaleData()`. Somehow you've got an old version of the tutorial, see [this tutorial](https://satijalab.org/seurat/pbmc3k_tutorial.html) compiled 22 March, 2018.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems RStudio server doesn't know it's limitations. Currently, Projects are limited to 1GB of RAM. Using [the R package](https://github.com/krlmlr/ulimit) `ulimit` which mirrors the function of `ulimit` and allows implementation of memory limits in linux I was able to set my own limitations within the R session. After setting the limit to 1GB I see the `ulimit` limitation being tripped when invoking `ScaleData()`. Looks like a case of exceeding available system resources.